# Is it possible to include a templated blob text into values.yaml?

Tags: templates, text, yaml, kubernetes-helm

For motives of backwards compatibility (and to reduce the burden of having to update src code) follows:

I have an user input:

$values.yaml

```
output:
  endpoint: MYENDPOINT
specialFile: 
  config1: |-
    Some very nicely formated text.
    Wow, such sample. 
    Much text.
    [...]
  config2: |-
    # this is also text but i need to remove |- for interpretation
    {{- $.Files.Get "configs/include.conf" | nindent 4 }}
```

That i want to replace with a blob of text:

$configs/include.conf

```
<match **>
  @type http
  endpoint_url    {{ .Values.output.endpoint }}
  serializer      json
</match>
```

So that  output replaces var on text and text replaces value on values.yaml. Is this possible?
I know this is something that is pretty close to impossible. I already saw someone replacing values.yaml with itself (didnt try myself) but is this possible?

Or can i overwrite the .Values.specialFile.configs2 value without writing directly into the .Values file and overwriting the variable somehow, maybe using templates?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by processing the included file as nested template with `tpl`:

```yaml
{{ $endpoint := "MYENDPOINT" }}
output:
  endpoint: {{ $endpoint }}
specialFile: 
  config1: |-
    Some very nicely formated text.
    Wow, such sample. 
    Much text.
    [...]
  config2: |-
    # this is also text but i need to remove |- for interpretation
    {{- tpl ($.Files.Get "configs/include.conf") $endpoint | nindent 4 }}
```

To avoid repetition, I put the endpoint in a variable and passed it to the loaded template. Therefore, it will be available as `{{.}}` there:

```
<match **>
  @type http
  endpoint_url    {{ . }}
  serializer      json
</match>
```